# How to integrate paypal in python django application

Tags: django, paypal

I am using python django framework. I need to integrate paypal in my app. Can some one suggest how to do that? And is there any tutorials or helpful links to do that?

I have searched a lot, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: [See Here](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

django-paypal app [django-paypal](https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal)
[here is the tutorial](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/overview.html)